# How do I create custom calculations on Groupby objects in pandas with a new row below each object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thank you for taking the time to read through my question. I hope you can help.

I have a large DataFrame with loads of columns. One column is an ID with multiple classes on which I would like to calculate totals and other custom calculations based on the columns above it.

The DataFrame columns look something like this:

[image: | ID | CLASS | AREA | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | ||||||___|]

I would like to calculate the Total AREA for each ID for all the CLASSES. Then I need to calculate the custom totals for the VAR columns using the variables from the other columns. In the end I would like to have a series of grouped IDs that look like this:

[image]

I hope that this make sense. The current thinking I have applied is to use the following code:

`df = pd.read_csv(data.csv)`

`df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['AREA'].sum())`

This provides me with a list of all the summed areas, which I can store in a variable to append back to the original dataframe through the ID and CLASS column. However, I am unsure how I get the other calculations done, as shown above. On top of that, I am not sure how to get the final DataFrame to mimic the above table format.

I am just starting to understand Pandas and constantly having to teach myself and ask for help when it gets rough.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. I am open to providing more information and clarity on the problem if this question is insufficient. Thank you.

Comment: Is it correct that your ´unique´ ID has duplicates?
It is much easier to answer your question if you provide a example DataFrame that can be copied easily.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your formulas correctly.

First you can simplify your formula by using the built-in `sum()` function:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.3], 'Class':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2],'AREA':[350,200,15,5000,65,280,70],
             'VAR1':[24,35,47,12,26,12,78], 'VAR2':[1.5,1.2,1.1,1.4,2.3,4.5,0.8], 'VAR3':[200,300,400,500,600,700,800]}) 

df.groupby(['ID']).sum()['AREA']
```

This will give the mentioned list

```
ID
1.1     550
1.2    5080
1.3     350
Name: AREA, dtype: int64
```

For Area Class 1 you just have to add a `key()`to the `groupby()` command:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Class']).sum()['AREA']
```

Resulting in:

```
ID   Class
1.1  1         350
     2         200
1.2  1          15
     2        5000
     3          65
1.3  1         280
     2          70
Name: AREA, dtype: int64
```

Since you want to sum up the square of the sum over each `Class` we can add both approaches together:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Class']).apply(lambda x: x['AREA'].sum()**2).groupby('ID').sum()

With the result 
ID
1.1      162500
1.2    25004450
1.3       83300
dtype: int64
```

I recommend to strip the command apart and try to understand each step. If you need further assistance just ask.